# My sharedPreference always returns default value

Tags: java, android, android-recyclerview, sharedpreferences, android-glide

I know that this question was asked many time and sorry for repeating it but I simply don't know what to do.

I am using Glide for loading images from server into my `RecycleView` and it's listener so when my images are loaded, it should save int 1 and then in my fragment, where my `RecycleView` is, I am getting that SharedPreferences int and check if it is not 1 than my `RecycleView` xml go INVISIBLE/GONE and then finally I check if some of my `RecycleView` are GONE/INVISIBLE all my layout should be gone, so that my layout is loaded after all my images are loaded.

But the problem is that my default value in my `SharedPreference` is always triggered, and I don't know why...
I also tried with `PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences()` but nothing different.

My adapter glide:

```
Glide.with(context)
     .load(listaSvihMembersa.get(i).getImageUrl())
     .circleCrop()
     .placeholder(R.drawable.ic_joint)
     .listener(new RequestListener<Drawable>() {
         @Override
         public boolean onLoadFailed(@Nullable GlideException e, Object model, Target<Drawable> target, boolean isFirstResource) {
             return false;
         }

         @Override
         public boolean onResourceReady(Drawable resource, Object model, Target<Drawable> target, DataSource dataSource, boolean isFirstResource) {
             SharedPreferences sp = context.getSharedPreferences("mortgage", MODE_PRIVATE);
             sp.edit().putInt("motgageList", 1).apply();
             return true;
        }})
        .into(binding.detailedListIMG);
   }
```

and my fragment where I get SharedPref

```
 private void setMortgageRecycleView(List<MortgageLiabilities> mortgageLiabilitiesList) {
    mortgageRecycleView = binding.rvMortgageList;
    mortgageRecycleView.animate().translationY(0);

    MortgageAdapter adapter = new MortgageAdapter(mortgageLiabilitiesList, context, this, listaSvihMembersa,mortgageRecycleView);
    mortgageRecycleView.setAdapter(adapter);
    SharedPreferences sp = context.getSharedPreferences("mortgage",MODE_PRIVATE);
    int idNmbr = sp.getInt("motgageList", 0);
    if (idNmbr != 1){
        mortgageRecycleView.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        Log.i(TAG, "visibility motgageListe: " + mortgageRecycleView.getVisibility());
    }
    else {
        mortgageRecycleView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        Log.i(TAG, "visibility motgageListe: " + mortgageRecycleView.getVisibility());
    }
    mortgageRecycleView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(context));
    mortgageRecycleView.setHasFixedSize(true);
}
```

Here, I check if any of `Recycleviews` are invisible:

```
 if (mortgageRecycleView.getVisibility() == View.INVISIBLE || loansRecycleViews.getVisibility() == View.INVISIBLE
                    || otherRecycleView.getVisibility() == View.INVISIBLE || creditCardRecycleView.getVisibility() == View.INVISIBLE){
     binding.constraintLayout.setVisibility(View.GONE);
     Toast.makeText(context, "Ne moze da ucita,root view je GONE", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
 }
```

EDIT: My shared_pref.xml file

```
<map>
    <int name="motgageList" value="1" />
</map>
```

Comment: please use break point and check shared pref xml file once you saved data.

will suggest you to use constant for PREFERANCE and key name.

Comment: @Yogendra i checked my shared_pref.xml file and edited question..it said correct value...

Comment: @Yogendra ok i reinstalled my app delete data from storage and now i getting an error when i try to open my shared_pref.xml errod said no such file or directorium

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Glide is executing an asynchronous task, so the most of the cases your code will reach `int idNmbr = sp.getInt("motgageList", 0);` before the callback `onResourceReady` is called.

Shared preferences are not a good choice here, you can use a custom callback and pass it to your adapter.